# xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser has no attribute '_parser' in python-3.x

Tags: xml, python-2.7, python-3.x, xml-parsing

Trying to run this code in python-3.x does not work but works fine in 2.7. Looking in C:\Python34\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py I see that the python3 imports the C implementation of ElementTree while python2 does not. How can I solve this? Like forcing ElementTree to not import the C implementation.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser

class CustomXMLParser(XMLParser):
    def __init__(self, html=0, target=None, encoding=None):
        XMLParser.__init__(self, html, target, encoding)
        self._parser.CommentHandler = self.handle_comments

    def handle_comments(self):
        pass

tree = ElementTree.parse(path, CustomXMLParser())
```

I have also tried ElementTree.XMLTreeBuilder but that works only in python2.

Thanks!